# Is my pc suitable for this graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Will my aspire X3812 be suitable for Nvidia GeForce GT 440 PCI Express Graphics Card with HDMI Low Profile HDCP. 
My acer has a quad CPU Q8300@2.50ghz
Intel (R) core (Tm)2

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you buy the GT 440 it will not be able to run on your system without a new power supply unit.

According to your computer's specifications, you only have a 220W PSU. the GT 440 will require at least [300W at a bare minimum](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-440-channel/specifications). Considering most estimates on GPUs for power are way too low, you'd probably need at least a 500W PSU to be on the safe side and allow for peripherals. You would definitely not be able to run this graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

according to your computer's [specifications](http://panam.acer.com/acerpanam/desktop/2010/acer/aspire/AspireX3812/AspireX3812sp2.shtml), it will take a PCI Express 2.0 low profile card.  So it should work.

Comment: Assuming the PSU can deliver...